# Split Strings by "|"

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm have some data in a txt file like in this form

> | item_id | channel | rank | head | body | source | timestamp | link_1_id | link_1_manual/auto | link_1_name/title | link_2_id | link_2_manual/auto | link_2_name/title | ... |

An i need to split it at the pipeline characters. However if I do:

```
String[] cols = line.split("|");
```

It will split the data by every character which is not what I want. What do I need to do to split by "|"?

Comment: You are actually splitting by empty string with that regex.

Comment: You need to know that `split(String regex)` uses [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to find places to split and `|` have special meaning in regex (is OR operator). To turn it off its special meaning you need to use \\ before it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
line.split("\\|");
```

The split pattern is interpreted as a regular expression, and `|` has a special meaning in regular expressions -- it's not interpreted as just the character alone.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** "|" has special meaning in Regular Expression.

**2.**  So use "\" before the "|" to remove its special meaning.

**Example:**

`String[] cols = line.split("\\|");`